# unable to select between two comma and A word using regex

Tags: regex

I have a text like

```
 aparna mall, indore, mahavir road <br>Map
```

I want to select " mahavir road " that is between , and `<br>Map`. Because i have so many such lines,

I tried 
         `,(.*)<br>Map`

it selects

```
     , indore, mahavir road <br>Map
```

i want to to select only from the last comma

how to use regex to select. Also any good link with examples of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work for you:

```
,([^,]*)<br>Map
```

[Try it online](http://regex101.com/r/sK4fA6) here.

Answer (score 1):

Use ungreedy notation:

```
.*,(.*?)<br>Map
```

or

```
,([^,]*)<br>Map
```

The last will match a comma an capture every thing that is not a comma before `<br>Map`

Comment: sorry i tried the ungreedy it selects from `indore, mahavir road ` (in the group, i dont what `indore,` to be selected